# Android Studio Navigation Drawer ListView Divider

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, divider

How can I only have one divider for the listview in Navigation Drawer? I tried using android:divider but that produces multiple lines! I only want a line after my 3rd item. How can I do that? (Sorry can't post image because of reputation)

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30916946/android-navigationview-menu-group-divider if you are using a menu resource

Comment: how can i use the menu thing?

Comment: the menu thing doesn't work

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30243365/how-to-add-one-section-separator-for-navigation-drawer-in-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't by default. One way you can do it as a workaround is by adding a conditional to your `getView` method, check if the `position` is 2 (third item) and add the divider to it -- maybe as an additional layout.