# Add one section separator for Navigation Drawer in Android

Tags: android, android-menu, navigationview

I have a navigation drawer like this image. I want to add a section separator . It seems simple but I can't find anything on the web that was useful for my case.

## - **Add a line separator below Express**

### **Add a line separator below My Information**

[image]

```
        <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:title="Express">
    <menu>
        <group
            android:id="@+id/me"
            android:checkableBehavior="single">
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_balance_transfer"
                android:icon="@mipmap/icon_wallet_transfer"
                android:title="Balance Transfer" />

            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_load_money"
                android:icon="@mipmap/icon_load_money"
                android:title="Load Money" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_report"
                android:icon="@mipmap/icon_history"
                android:title="Report" />
        </group>
    </menu>
</item>
<item android:title="My Information">
    <menu>

        <group
            android:id="@+id/menu_nav_temp_gid"
            android:checkableBehavior="none">
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_profile"
                android:icon="@mipmap/icon_profile"
                android:title="My Account" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_changePassword"
                android:icon="@mipmap/icon_change"
                android:title="Change Password" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_ViewUser"
                android:icon="@mipmap/ic_view_user"
                android:title="View User" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_addUser"
                android:icon="@mipmap/icon_adduser"
                android:title="Add User" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_addScheme"
                android:icon="@mipmap/icon_add_scheme"
                android:title="Add Scheme" />

            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_logout"
                android:icon="@mipmap/icon_logout"
                android:title="Log Out" />

        </group>
    </menu>
</item>
```

i had done this code
if i takes express and my info in a separate group than it takes padding

suggest me how to achive this ..

Comment: You mean you want to remove those paddings in group title?

Comment: nope i just want to set a divider below express and my information ..

Comment: i can do that by what answer given by #rishikesh but problem is than it is treated as submenu item and it automaticaly takes padding

Comment: As a suggestion: Create a recyclerView to do this can time less time.

Comment: yeh i know ..i can add a section navigation drawer..but i am finding something how we can do with navigation view

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30243365/how-to-add-one-section-separator-for-navigation-drawer-in-android ? The accepted answer there is to add new groups with different ids. Each group gets a separate line drawn above it.

Comment: @Tufan try to my updated answer......

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this....

```
    <group>
    <item android:title="Express">
    </item>
    </group>



            <group
                android:id="@+id/grpid1"
                android:checkableBehavior="single">
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/nav_balance_transfer"
                    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                    android:title="Balance Transfer" />

                <item
                    android:id="@+id/nav_load_money"
                    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                    android:title="Load Money" />
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/nav_report"
                    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                    android:title="Report" />
            </group>



    <group>
    <item android:title="My Information">



        </item>
    </group>


            <group
                android:id="@+id/grpid2"
                android:checkableBehavior="none">
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/nav_profile"
                    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                    android:title="My Account" />
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/nav_changePassword"
                    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                    android:title="Change Password" />
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/nav_ViewUser"
                    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                    android:title="View User" />
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/nav_addUser"
                    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                    android:title="Add User" />
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/nav_addScheme"
                    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                    android:title="Add Scheme" />

                <item
                    android:id="@+id/nav_logout"
                    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                    android:title="Log Out" />

            </group>


    </menu>
```

It looks like you just need to give your `group` tags unique ID's.

```
<group android:id="@+id/ids">
    <!-- Divider will appear above this item -->
    <item ... />
</group>
```

[image]

Sure @Tufan I can solve this problem also

Do this...  put these lines to your `dimen.xml`

```
<dimen name="design_navigation_padding_top_default" tools:override="true">0dp</dimen>
<dimen name="design_navigation_separator_vertical_padding" tools:override="true">0dp</dimen>
<dimen name="design_navigation_padding_bottom" tools:override="true">0dp</dimen>
```

> dimen.xml

```
<resources
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    >

    <dimen name="design_navigation_padding_top_default" tools:override="true">0dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="design_navigation_separator_vertical_padding" tools:override="true">0dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="design_navigation_padding_bottom" tools:override="true">0dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="navigation_separator_vertical_padding">0dp</dimen>

</resources>
```

> New Screenshot remove padding by add this..

[image]

Comment: it can be a solution but look at express and my info they are not looking like main item ..when you set like this it treat as group item and it takes padding

Answer (score 0):

> Here is your Solution Do like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <group>
                <item
                    android:title="Express">
                </item>
        </group>

    <menu>

        <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_camera"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
                android:title="Import" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
                android:title="Gallery" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
                android:title="Slideshow" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_manage"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_manage"
                android:title="Tools" />
         </group>

    </menu>

    <item android:title="Communicate">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_share"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
                android:title="Share" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_send"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
                android:title="Send" />
        </menu>
    </item>

</menu>
```

Comment: if i done like this than it sets padding to express ..it consider it as a child...i already tried that

Comment: i don't want any padding to the main item ..and in your code it will set padding to express

Answer (score 0):

You should create groups with different IDs in your menu XML file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group
        android:id="@+id/menu_section_1"
        android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/drawer_item_1"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_item_1"
            android:title="@string/drawer_item_1"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/drawer_item_2"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_item_2"
            android:title="@string/drawer_item_2"/>
    </group>
    <group
        android:id="@+id/menu_section_2"
        android:checkableBehavior="none">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/drawer_item_3"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_item_3"
            android:title="@string/drawer_item_3" >
        </item>
    </group>
</menu>
```

Comment: alex i know about that look at my xml ..if i take all items in separate group than i will have line separator ..but it reflcet on my look an feel that i don't want to change

Comment: and if i put express and my info in group than it treated as sub item and it takes pading

Answer (score 0):

This is the activities layout. You should place the other things inside the frame layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<!-- your content layout -->
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/content_frame">



</FrameLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer_view"/>

 </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

below is my drawer_view file in res/menu directory

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group>
        <item
            android:title="Label1"
            android:id="@+id/asd">
        </item>
   </group>


    <group
        android:checkableBehavior="single"
        android:id="@+id/nav_file_navigation">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_all_files"
            android:icon="@drawable/all"
            android:title="All Files" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_memory_card"
            android:icon="@drawable/sd_card"
            android:title="Memory Card"
            />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_pictures"
            android:icon="@drawable/picture"
            android:title="Pictures" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_videos"
            android:icon="@drawable/play_button"
            android:title="Video" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_music"
            android:icon="@drawable/music_player"
            android:title="Music" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_documents"
            android:icon="@drawable/document"
            android:title="Documents" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_download"
            android:icon="@drawable/download"
            android:title="Downloads"
            />
    </group>

    <group>
        <item
            android:title="Label1"
            android:id="@+id/asd">
        </item>
   </group>


     <group
         android:checkableBehavior="single"
         android:id="@+id/nav_others"
         >
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_certificate"
            android:icon="@drawable/certificate"
            android:title="Set Certificate"/>
         <item
             android:id="@+id/nav_email"
             android:icon="@drawable/mail_gray"
             android:title="Email"
             />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_setting"
            android:icon="@drawable/settings"
            android:title="Settings"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_help"
            android:icon="@drawable/help"
            android:title="Help" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_log_out"
            android:icon="@drawable/log_out"
            android:title="Log Out" />

     </group>
</menu>
```

This is a navigation drawer header:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="140dp"
    android:background="@color/lightGray"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/navigation_header_image"
        android:background="@color/lightGray"
        android:src="@drawable/drawer_header"
        android:padding="16dp"
        />


</FrameLayout>
```

In the activity's on create() method

```
mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    mNavigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
    mNavigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);
    mNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new      NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            item.setChecked(true);
            onNavigationItemClicked(item);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

before on create declare this variables.

```
public NavigationView mNavigationView;
public DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
```

onNavigationClicked() method is

```
public void onNavigationItemClicked(MenuItem item){
 //Do whatever you want to do with item. You can get its title and depending
 //on the title you can do what you want.

 mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
}
```

Comment: buddy check my question again ..you set all the item in a single group ..where is the divider for group item ..atleast read my question properly

Comment: somwhat correct but it will treat  android:title="Label1" as a child item and it set pading ..that i don't want

Comment: need some hack i think so

Comment: In mine project it is just like your picture in the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121714/discussion-between-gunescelil-and-tufan).

Answer (score 0):

What about remove the `<Menu>` and wrap the separator item with a group.

From this:

```
<item android:title="Express">
<menu>
    <group
        android:id="@+id/me"
        android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_balance_transfer"
            android:icon="@mipmap/icon_wallet_transfer"
            android:title="Balance Transfer" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_load_money"
            android:icon="@mipmap/icon_load_money"
            android:title="Load Money" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_report"
            android:icon="@mipmap/icon_history"
            android:title="Report" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

To this

```
    <group android:id="@+id/id1">
       <item android:title="Express"
        android:enabled="false">
    </group>
    <group
        android:id="@+id/me"
        android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_balance_transfer"
            android:icon="@mipmap/icon_wallet_transfer"
            android:title="Balance Transfer" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_load_money"
            android:icon="@mipmap/icon_load_money"
            android:title="Load Money" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_report"
            android:icon="@mipmap/icon_history"
            android:title="Report" />
    </group>
```

Don't forget set the item wraped with `android:enabled="false"` to remove touch effects.

Source: [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30605286/navigationview-insert-divider-without-subgroup)

Comment: it will set pading to Express